# Why page showing content when browse to site.com/file.php/

Tags: php, .htaccess, cpanel

I got notifications from Google webmaster tool that I have duplicated page titles.
It was properly to browse mysite.com/file.php but I do not know why `mysite.com/file.php/` is showing some of content by file.php. 
Please advise how to remove/disable content showing when browse `mysite.com/file.php/`

Comment: What do you mean by _showing some of content_ ?

Comment: Check directory permissions, htaccess file

Comment: Does content mean some code of your file.php ?

Comment: it seems like content that generated by file.php is showing but the css file in another directory not been read.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1st: You might have a filename `file.php` **and** directory `file.php`. Check those out.

2nd: You might have `.htaccess` rewrite rule, that messes stuff up, if you do check out the syntax on that.

Comment: you can't have both *file* **and** *folder* with same name.

Comment: @poncha tell that to Windows ;)

Comment: @jprofitt you can't have that in windows either. TIAS. i just created folder "foo.txt" and then i'm unable to create text file with same name (on win7)

Comment: @DainisAbols riddle shmiddle.. ;) http://i49.tinypic.com/15g8l1t.png riddle me that then ;)

Comment: @Dainis Abols, I have no directory file.php, then what I have to write to .htaccess.?

Answer (score 1):

When you hit `/file.php`, or `/file.php/` what changes is *pathname* that the browser "sees".
In first case, it is `/`, in second case it's `/file.php`.

Hence, when you use relative path (to images, stylesheets, etc), in second case the browser will send requests to wrong URIs.

To avoid that, use `<base url="http://example.com/path/to/site/root/">` in your HTML

Comment: It seems like browser sees file.php then Google is treat that I have 2 same title pages. Should I have to add something to .htacess ?

Comment: Google does not traverse urls just for a sake of it - it goes by links on your website (or links **to** your website from other sites). Do not construct links with trailing slash if you dont want this to happen...